# Dynamically name variable from for loop

Tags: oracle

I am writing a `procedure` in oracle, when I am getting a `variable as rowtype`.

I am trying to `achieve` a test condition based on for `loop`

```
FOR idx in 1..10 LOOP
   IF POST.SI_AMOUNT||idex <> 0 THEN
   NULL;
   END IF; 
END LOOP;
```

I have columns in table like this

```
 SI_AMOUNT1,

 SI_AMOUNT2,

 SI_AMOUNT3,

 SI_AMOUNT4,

 SI_AMOUNT5,

 SI_AMOUNT6,

 SI_AMOUNT7,

 SI_AMOUNT8,

 SI_AMOUNT9,

 SI_AMOUNT10
```

I want to check all columns value by using for loop. is this possible in oracle?

Comment: may be some usage of  `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` ..  `RETURNING INTO` ..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks like your table design violates the [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). If you fix this error, I guess, you'll lose a need to iterate throw a columns in such manner.

Next, statement `POST.SI_AMOUNT||idex <> 0` you had wrote, means *Take the value of `POST.SI_AMOUNT` variable, concatenate it with the value of `idex` variable and compare concatenation result with zero using implicit datatype conversion*.

At last, PL/SQL, as other non-script languages, have no ability to iterate throw variables list. There are no any ability to do this simplier than direct use of ten `IF` conditions, but the best way, as I said, is to redesign the table and to eliminate this need at all.